# How to apply Quill Snow Theme in p:textEditor on primefaces 6.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, quill

I'm using the primefaces 6.2 with jsf.

I'm trying to apply the snow theme to the p:textEditor component, which uses Quill.

I still do not understand how I apply the snow theme.

I include this line:

```
<link href = "https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

But it din't work.

Can anyone put an example here?

Comment: p:textEditor already uses snow theme by default...

Comment: in my case, it's not applying that white background and the toolbar is split in half, but with buttons only at the top.

Is it possible to post photos here in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code that you create a new instance of your Quill Editor, use 
`theme: 'snow'`, like this:

```
let quillEditor = new Quill('#myIdEditor', { theme : 'snow' });
```

See [the documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/themes/)

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using Quill separately.

To create the editor, just use the primefaces tag <p:textEditor> </p:textEditor> without using JS.

Doubt is exactly at that point.

How to apply the theme without the call via JS?